# Illegal Start of Expression

Tags: java

** Problem statement:

You are given a list of N people who are attending ACM-ICPC World Finals. Each of them are either well versed in a topic or they are not. Find out the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know. And also find out how many teams can know that maximum number of topics.

Note Suppose a, b, and c are three different people, then (a,b) and (b,c) are counted as two different teams.

Input Format

The first line contains two integers, N and M, separated by a single space, where N represents the number of people, and M represents the number of topics. N lines follow.
Each line contains a binary string of length M. If the ith line's jth character is 1, then the ith person knows the jth topic; otherwise, he doesn't know the topic.

Constraints 
2≤N≤500 
1≤M≤500

Output Format

On the first line, print the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know. 
On the second line, print the number of 2-person teams that can know the maximum number of topics.

** Problem:
I have 2 errors ("illegal start of expression" and " ';' expected") when I want to declare the 2 numbers maxTopic and numTeam as:

public static int maxTopic = 0;
public static int numTeam = 0;

** Code:

```html
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ppl = in.nextInt(); // Number of people
        int topic = in.nextInt(); // Number of topics
        
        int A[]; // Array A to store information about topics known by everyone
        public static int maxTopic = 0; // Maximum number of topics known
        public static int numTeam = 0; // Maximum number of teams that know maxTopic

        
        /* Read the information about topics 
           and save it to the array A */
        for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++)
            A[i] = in.nextInt();
        
        /* Now call the method addCheck() to check each pair of people */
        for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++) 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ppl; j++) 
                Solution.addCheck(A[i], A[j], topic);
        
            
        System.out.println(maxTopic);
        System.out.println(numTeam);
    }
    
    /** 
     * Method used to add up 2 given numbers, check their sum,
     * and update the values of maxTopic and numTeam (if possible)
     * @param a First number
     * @param b Second number
     * @param digit Number of digits for a and b
     */
    
    public void addCheck(int a, int b, int digit) {
        int sum = a + b; // Calculate the sum of a and b
        int numTopic = 0; // Number of topics known for a and b
        boolean update = false; // True if the current pair has been used to update numTeam
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= digit; i++) {
            if (Solution.getNthDigit(sum, i) != 0) 
                numTopic++;
                if (numTopic > maxTopic) 
                    maxTopic = numTopic;
                if ((update == false) && (maxTopic == numTopic)) {
                    numTeam++;
                    update = true;
                }
        }
    }
          
        
   /** 
    * Get the nth digit of an integer
    * @param number The number being considered
    * @param n The digit (starting from 1, counted from right to left)
    * @return int The value of the nth digit
    * Example: getNthDigit(123, 10, 1) produces 3
    */
   public int getNthDigit(int number, int n) {    
       return (int) ((number / Math.pow(10, n - 1)) % 10);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use public static modifiers within a method. Those are used for class-level declarations only. Since you use the variables in other methods, declare them in the class. Note, your addCheck method **should** be declared static.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Can you tell me why addCheck should be static?

Comment: @HuyenNguyen: you're calling it in a static way. Isn't the compiler complaining about this?

Comment: oh yeah, the compiler complains about both addCheck and getNthDigit: error: non-static method getNthDigit(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context. Is this because I'm calling the methods, even though no object has been constructed yet? Thanks!

Comment: @HuyenNguyen: no, it has nothing to do with that. If you created an object, you'd still get the error. Again, it's because **you're calling the object in a *static* way**. You're calling it off the class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Java, and I'm not sure what you meant by calling the object in a static way. Could you please explain a bit more? Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: @HuyenNguyen: You are calling the method off of the class name and not off of an instance. You're also calling it from within a static method. Please read about static (and instance) methods as this is a fundamental concept that has to be nailed if you're to progress.

Comment: Thanks, I've read about them. So, do I always have to make sure that called methods inside a static method are static?

Comment: @HuyenNguyen: If you want to call an *instance* method from within a static method, you must call it on an *instance* -- on an object.